# find: missing argument to `-exec' in Cygwin

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I am trying to get HTML files from `component` folder and building new `component` folder and trying to insert that `component` (New) folder in `build` folder for Which I am using the given code:

```
find components -iname '*.html' -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ \\;
```

But when I do this I am getting the given error:

```
find: missing argument to -exec
```

Please give me some solution to resolve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achive with the rsync at the end? It would only produce an unneccessary amount of doubled listings of the directory paths?

Comment: I am trying to copy html files from component folder and pushing the component folder into build folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper format of `find` is:

```
find components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R {} \;
```

Comment: ok I try to do 

find components -iname '*.html' -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ \\;

but it's not coping the components folder's files in build

I am still getting the same error 

find: missing argument to `-exec'

kindly tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: @gouravsachdeva Why did you use `\\;`? He explicitly said `\;`.

Comment: @Kusalananda because if i didn't put \\; than i will get ERROR : npm ERR! Unexpected token ';' at 9:193

Comment: @gouravsachdeva `npm`? You should update the question with information about what it is you're actually doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda I am trying to get html files from component folder and building new component folder and trying to insert that component(New) folder in build folder 

For Which I am Using the given code : 

find components -iname '*.html' -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ \\;

But when i do this I am getting the given error :
<br>
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @romeo-ninov Hello Sir Can you please tell me guide me how can i do the upper stuff. I'm using cygwin in windows.

Comment: @gouravsachdeva, I do not get what do you mean by "upper shuff" . Uf you have new questions please use "Ask question", do not use comments, this is not a forum.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No No that's the same question I am asking 

_Below is my requirement_

**I am trying to get html files from component folder and building new component folder and trying to insert that component(New) folder in build folder For Which I am Using the given code : `find components -iname '*.html' -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ \\;` But when i do this I am getting the given error : <br> `find: missing argument to `-exec' `**

Comment: This is not correct. In a Windows command prompt, the semicolon does not need escaping (this isn't bash/csh/etc), so there should be 0 backslashes in front of the semicolon. (IDK about the rsync syntax.)

Comment: @Conrad Cygwin is, as far as I know, presenting the user with a `bash` shell, not with a Windows command prompt.

Comment: @Kusalananda that is true that the OP didn't specify which shell they were using - these commands can be run in a regular Windows command prompt, so it looks like there are different reqs for the different environments.

Comment: @Conrad Three things: The title mentions Cygwin, which means `bash`. The question is tagged with [tag:shell], which means "some Unix shell". This is the Unix & Linux site and the user is using standard Unix commands. They also accepted this answer. In all, there is no indication that the user is running at a Windows command prompt.

Comment: @Kusalananda cygwin does not necessarily mean bash; I use cygwin commands all the time the plain Windows command prompt, without any *nix shell. Maybe the OP thought a Windows command prompt counted as a "shell;" who knows. For historical records, it's good to note the difference.

Comment: @Conrad There is nothing in the question that implies this, nor would this answer be accepted if that was the case. The way the Window command prompt works is uninteresting and off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues from the original formulation of the question:

1. The command executed with `-exec` must be terminated by `;`.
2. The `rsync` command is malformed (or *was*, rather, in the [original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/388265/2)).

This is what I *think* you may want:

```
find components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ ';'
```

To copy a file with `rsync` you will have to say where it is to be copied *to*.  Here, I have assumed that you want to copy all found files to `./build/`.

**After question was updated:**

The command that `find` executes must be terminated by a `;`-character that is protected from the shell. The correct way to protect the `;` from the shell is to quote it using either `\;` or `';'`¹.

Since you are using `\\;`, you "undo" the quoting of the `;` and instead the `find` process will just see a terminating `\`.  Since it can't see any `;`, it will complain about missing arguments.

You mentioned `npm` somewhere.  This is is a package manager for JavaScript.  Since you mentioned this, it leads me to believe that you're not running `find` from the command line but from some sort of script.  Quoting would (potentially) work differently from within a script depending on the particular grammatical and syntactical rules of that scripting language.

To properly resolve this issue, it would be most helpful to see the actual invocation of `find` in the context of the script that invokes it.

Until such time that the question is updated with this information, the answer that I have given here is as close as anyone could get.

---

<sup>¹ (or `";"` or more exotic forms like `$';'` or `$'\u003b'` depending on the shell, `';'` being the most portable)</sup>

Comment: Note that strictly speaking _quoting_ and _escaping_ are the same thing in this context. backslash is a quoting operator in the shell syntax. One can say that `\x` is a quoted `x` and that `'x'` is escaping `x`. backslash is often used for 2 very different things: *remove* the special meaning of some characters (like `\;` here, a form of _quoting_), or *add* a special meaning to some characters (like `\n` that becomes a newline, though not  in this context), both of which are (confusingly) generally called _escaping_. Personally, I prefer refering to the former as _quoting_ as less ambiguous.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You seem to have a point there. I will update.

Comment: The semicolon quoting is unnecessary (although harmless) here; the OP definitely does not want to escape the semicolon with a backslash (this is not bash/tcsh/etc).

Comment: @Conrad You will notice that using `-exec ... \\;` will result in calling `find` with ``-exec ... \`` and that the unescaped semi-colon would not be passed to `find` at all. Why would the user _not_ want to escape/quote the semi-colon according to you and what should they do instead?

Answer (score 1):

If run from a standard **MS-DOS command prompt** using the **cygwin** binary of *find.exe*, it may just be that you don't need to escape the final '**;**' (since it's not a sh/bash/... that interprets the command line but DOS, for which the ';' is not a special character) :

So I would try :

```
find components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ ;
```